# Can a bounty be redacted?

Tags: support, bounty, answered-questions

I could swear there was a 500 point bounty on this question: [How to fix Bang and Olufsen Audio for HP laptops?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899021/how-to-fix-bang-and-olufsen-audio-for-hp-laptops/945969#945969)

...and I could swear I saw it go into a 9 hour grace period last night. But upon looking at it tonight I don't see the slightest hint there was ever a bounty on the question.

Which begs the question could the bounty have been redacted with some sort of magic wand? To the best of my knowledge once a bounty is pledged the  sponsor looses the points and it is awarded to the accepted answer and lacking that 50% is awarded to the answer with the most upvotes.

Can a bounty simply disappear?

Answer (score 6):

It didn't simply disappear. It wasn't awarded to anyone, that's all. Look at [the revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/899021/revisions):

[image]

You need answers with score >= 2 for automatic awards.

Comment: Ohh I thought it was the answer with the most points. I didn't realize there was a minimum of 2. I should have asked you to vote on it :)

Comment: Isn't the grace period still in place for another 6 hours? And don't automatic awards happen once the grace period is over, such that @WinEunuuchs2Unix's answer might still receive half the bounty if its score rises to +2 or above?

Comment: @EliahKagan I don't know what exactly Win saw, or when exactly they saw it, but once those entries get added to the revision history, that's it for the bounty. When the bounty is in the grace period, there a notice below the question saying that's in the grace period. Like this, maybe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203601/270345 I'll look for a screenshot, but meanwhile, you can watch https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45541245/revisions for an example (bounty ending in a few minutes)

Comment: @EliahKagan also, if you look at the timestamps, the ending notice was posted 8days + ~1hr after the bounty was set (so 7 days for the normal bounty period, and 24 hours for the grace period, and 1 hour for the cron jobs to run, I suppose).

Comment: Excellent point about the timestamps; it appears I was completely wrong and that @WinEunuuchs2Unix was correct in thinking the grace period was over. (I'm deleting my answer.)

Comment: @EliahKagan Thank you for trying. As a side note when I post a bounty and there are no good answers, I practically beg established authors here to write an answer. Then I can award the bounty and not have it disappear into the bit bucket.

Answer (score 3):

Moderators can remove bounties, but this is only done under very special and rather rare circumstances (mostly if a question needs to be closed).

Bounty history is [in the revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/899021/revisions)